# VBA drag and drop file to user form to get filename and path

Tags: excel, vba, drag-and-drop, userform

I'd like to learn a new trick, but I'm not 100% confident it is possible in VBA, but I thought I'd check with the gurus here.

What I'd like to do is eschew the good-old getopenfilename or browser window (it has been really difficult to get the starting directory set on our network drive) and I'd like to create a VBA user form where a user can drag and drop a file from the desktop or a browser window on the form and VBA will load the filename and path.  Again, I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it is or if someone has done it before I'd appreciate pointers.  I know how to set up a user form, but I don't have any real code outside of that.  If there is something I can provide, let me know.

Thanks for your time and consideration!

Comment: Found an answer and answered my own question Mr. Downboats, whoever you are.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I figured out a way to achieve this.  As far as I can tell, it can only be done using a treeview control.  You may have to right click your toolbox to find and add it.  It will be there under "additional controls" or something like that.  You'll need two things aside from the control.

In the `UserForm_Initialize` sub you will need the following line of code to enable drag and drop:  `TreeView1.OLEDropMode = ccOLEDropManual`:

```
UserForm_Initialize()
    TreeView1.OLEDropMode = ccOLEDropManual
End Sub
```

Then you will need the `Private Sub TreeView1_OLEDragDrop` event.  I've omitted all the parameters to save space.  They should be easy enough to find. In that sub simply declare a string, maybe `strPath` or something like that to hold the file name and path and set `strPath = Data.Files(1)` and that will get the file name and path of a file that the user drags to the TreeView control.  This assumes that the user only drags one file at a time, but as far as I can tell this should be something that can be done dragging multiple files if you experiment with it.

```
Private Sub TreeView1_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    StrPath = Data.Files(1)
End Sub
```

Edit:  You will also need to add a reference to `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0`

I've also added example code.

Comment: thank you this is useful ! I don't understand why someone would give you a negative point... this is really annoying

Comment: could you post some code for user dragging multiple files ?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai I haven't actually done it with multiple files, but I assume it is possible.  I'll give you my best guess.  The DragDrop event produces the data.files object which is indexed starting at 1.  That's why I use `Data.Files(1)` to get the file name.  I haven't tested this so I can't promise anything, but I would assume that you could iterate over the Data.Files(1 to n) array to get multiple file paths.  Try something like `For intCounter = 1 to UBound(Data.Files)` where `intCounter` is an integer and retrieve all your file paths using `strPath = Data.Files(intCOunter)`. Should work.

Comment: Matt's solution is great, only need to make sure: Need to add the TreeView control that supports OLEDragDrop operation: Right click the Toolbox area showing all available controls.
Select "Additional controls..."
Include: "Microsoft TreeView control, version 6.0"

Comment: `For Each dataFile In Data.Files`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread. Future readers, If you are after some cool UI, you can checkout my [Github](https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS/blob/master/README.md#drag-and-drop-openfiledialog) for sample database using .NET wrapper dll. Which allows you to simply call a function and to open filedialog with **file-drag-and-drop** function. Result is returned as a JSONArray string.

code can be simple as

```
Dim FilePaths As String
    FilePaths = gDll.DLL.ShowDialogForFile("No multiple files allowed", False)
'Will return a JSONArray string.
'Multiple files can be opend by setting AllowMulti:=true
```

here what it looks like;

[image: In Action]

Comment: This is a really cool project. I think it was down-voted for not being a native solution but it's a neat idea.

Comment: hi Krish! thumbs up for the cool project. I want to know if it is feasible for distribution purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using Application Event WorkbookOpen. When a file gets dragged onto an open Excel Sheet it will try to open that file in Excel as a separate workbook which would trigger the above event. It's a bit of a pain but I used this link https://bettersolutions.com/vba/events/excel-application-level-events.htm as a reference.

Only issue is that if the file isn't an Excel file then it will have a popup and you can't run a VBScript to get rid of it since the Event won't run until you address the popup. A portion of my code below:

```
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

Dim path, pathExt As String
path = Wb.Name
pathExt = Mid(path, InStrRev(path, "."))

If pathExt = ".pdf" Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks(Wb.Name).Windows(1).Visible = False

Dim n As String
n = Wb.FullName

Wb.Close

Call DragnDrop.newSheet(n)

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

End Sub
```

Edit:
Forgot that you need to initialize the Application Events by posting the below code in any module

```
Option Explicit
'Variable to hold instance of class clsApp
Dim mcApp As clsApp

Public Sub Init()
    'Reset mcApp in case it is already loaded
    Set mcApp = Nothing
    'Create a new instance of clsApp
    Set mcApp = New clsApp 'Whatever you named your class module
    'Pass the Excel object to it so it knows what application
    'it needs to respond to
    Set mcApp.App = Application  'mcApp.Whatever you named this Public 
'WithEvents App As Application
End Sub
```

And then paste this code in ThisWorkbook Workbook_Open()

```
'Initialize the Application Events
Application.OnTime Now, "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!Init"
```