# Drag and drop multiple files to Userform

Tags: excel, vba, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag and drop more than one file on a Userform to get their paths. I managed it with one file thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569959/vba-drag-and-drop-file-to-user-form-to-get-filename-and-path).

When I change `FilePath = Data.files(1)` to `FilePath = Data.Files(2)` or `(i)`, I get a message "Table Expected". Should I create a Table and Redim it?

My work so far:

**This one does the job (opening the file and copying it into a selected sheet)**

```
Dim Wb, FilePath As String
Dim WbIni, WbCib As Workbook

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If FilePath = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Aucun fichier n'a été importé", vbCritical, "Anomalie"
    Unload UserForm1
    Exit Sub
End If

Set WbCib = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath)
MsgBox WbCib.Name

i = WbCib.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
WbCib.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & i).Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=WbIni.Worksheets("Target").Range("A1:A" & i)
WbIni.Sheets("Target").Activate
WbCib.Close

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

**This one initializes my TreeView for the drag and drop**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Wb = ThisWorkbook.Name
Set WbIni = ActiveWorkbook

TreeView1.OLEDropMode = ccOLEDropManual
End Sub
```

**This one gives me the file path. I think I need to loop it.**

```
Private Sub TreeView1_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)

    FilePath = Data.Files(1)
    Workbooks(Wb).Activate

    MsgBox FilePath

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `foreach` loop.  `foreach file in Data.Files`...

Comment: Drag and drop onto a userform? Learned something new today. Thanks.

Comment: @R.Roe Thanks for your answer. I think I've managed to do it with a for each. I'll keep you updated whenever I'm done (Success or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @R.Roe's comment, I managed to do what I wanted :

```
Dim x, y As Integer
Dim PathTable As String
Dim FilePath As Variant

Private Sub TreeView1_OLEDragDrop(Data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
Dim i As Integer

Workbooks(Wb).Activate

'Counting file paths I dropped
For Each FilePath In Data.Files()
    i = i + 1
Next FilePath

'Redim my table
ReDim PathTable(i)

i = 1

'Adding data to my table
For x = 0 To UBound(PathTable) - 1
    PathTable(x) = Data.Files(i)
    i = i + 1
Next x

'Just to make sure it works
For x = 0 To UBound(PathTable) - 1
    MsgBox PathTable(x)
Next x

End Sub
```

Cheers!