# VBA drag and drop a file into a user form without reference to "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0"

Tags: vba, outlook, drag-and-drop, userform

I want to be able to drag and drop files into a custom user form in my Outlook VBA macro. My searching has come up with many [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569959/vba-drag-and-drop-file-to-user-form-to-get-filename-and-path) all requiring "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0" which is not available as a reference on my network.

Is there a way to do it without this reference library?

Comment: I'm on my work network and so, although I have access to VBA, I can't import DLLs or use other languages.

Comment: No. That's the assembly that implements all of the basic Windows controls and the drag/drop functionality. How can you have Windows installed and be using VBA without having .NET on your computer?

Comment: You register the Window as accepting files with `DragAcceptFiles` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragacceptfiles. Then you subclass the Window https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Subclassing and respond to the `WM_DropFiles` message. There is a program here that shows how to process an `HDrop` https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/printclipexe-prints-any-text-or.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses - I actually managed to reference 'Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0" by adding the reference directly to the MSCOMCTL.OSX file which was already installed.